# Is there a way to reference "the current class" from a Javascript class method

Tags: javascript, oop

I'm wondering if there's a way to reference the "current class" rather than a class by name, from within a Javascript class.

For example:

```js
class MyBase{
    static makeNew(id){
        const newInstance = new --currentClass--;// magic happens here
        newInstance.id = id;
        return newInstance;
    }
}

class A extends MyBase{}
class B extends MyBase{}

const newA = A.makeNew(1);
const newB = B.makeNew(379);
```

Is there a way for me to write `MyBase::makeNew` in such a way that when it's called from the `A` class, it returns a new instance of `A`, but when called from the `B` class, it returns a new instance of `B`?

Comment: You are trying to make the constructor of your class a virtual function, which is impossible by definition (i.e., by the principles of OOP).

Comment: None of these classes have a constructor.  And for what I want to do, they can each have their own constructor defined if necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the call signatures are like:

```
A.makeNew(1);
B.makeNew(379);
```

That might look familiar - you can use `this` to reference the object it's being called on.

```js
class MyBase{
    static makeNew(id){
        const newInstance = new this();
        newInstance.id = id;
        return newInstance;
    }
}

class A extends MyBase{}
class B extends MyBase{}

const newA = A.makeNew(1);
const newB = B.makeNew(379);

console.log(newA instanceof A);
console.log(newB instanceof B);
```

Comment: Excellent - thanks.  I figured it was something pretty simple, but I wouldn't be the first programmer to be unsure exactly what `this` means in a given context.  Thanks again.